# Using arrays parsed from string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I have array created while truncating string:

```
IN=123.11.1
arr=$(echo $IN | tr "." "\n")
```

Printing everything:

```
for x in $arr
        do
        echo "[$x]"
        done
```

Have in output:

```
[123]
[11]
[1]
```

And this was expected.

But when I'm trying to print 0 element :

```
echo ${arr[0]}
```

I have output:

```
123 11 1
```

And

```
echo ${arr[1]}
```

Prints nothing.

What is wrong with using array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` to to read it correctly with custom `IFS`:

```
IN=123.11.1
IFS=. read -ra arr <<< "$IN"
```

Or else;

```
IFS=. arr=($(printf "%s" "$IN"))
```

**Verify the content of array:**

```
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="123" [1]="11" [2]="1")'
```

Your assignment: `arr=$(echo $IN | tr "." "\n")` is not even creating any array. It is creating a simple variable called `arr`. To verify you can always use:

```
declare -p arr
```